# How to integrate remote config to a flutter app?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-remote-config

I have to integrate firebase remote config to my flutter app. From the searches in various sites, I couldn't find the complete solution.

```
class RemoteConfigurartion{
  Future<RemoteConfig> setupRemoteConfig() async {
    String value =null;
    final RemoteConfig remoteConfig = await RemoteConfig.instance;

    remoteConfig.setConfigSettings(RemoteConfigSettings(debugMode: false));
    remoteConfig.setDefaults(<String, dynamic>{
      'riddle': "off",
    });
    try {
      // Using default duration to force fetching from remote server.
      await remoteConfig.fetch(expiration: const Duration(seconds: 0));
      await remoteConfig.activateFetched();
    } on FetchThrottledException catch (exception) {
      // Fetch throttled.
      print(exception);
    } catch (exception) {
      print(
          'Unable to fetch remote config. Cached or default values will be '
              'used');
    }
    return remoteConfig;
  }
}
```

This is what I found already. This the result I'm getting:

> No implementation found for method RemoteConfig#instance on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_remote_config

But I have added all the plugins in the pubspec.yaml and in android gradle folder

Can anyone help me to find out a complete solution to integrate remote config to a flutter app?

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you shared?

Comment: No implementation found for method RemoteConfig#instance on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_remote_config ,this the result I'm getting ,but I have added all the plugins in the pubspec.yaml and in android gradle folder @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: Did you rebuild your app and still get this error? MethodChannel was not found implies you added the plugin to `pubspec.yaml` while running the app. Flutter can hot reload dart code but not android, ios code. So you need to rebuild the app when the plugin you added uses platform code (eg: method channels)

Comment: Did you turn on Firebase Remote Config API?
https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/firebaseremoteconfig.googleapis.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that [firebase_core](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/core/usage) is initialized, and for Android, google-services.json should be in the `app` folder. Aside from that, there doesn't seem to be any issues on your code. You might've missed some steps during set up.

If you've just added the plugins, it's best to run the app using restart instead of hot reload to ensure that all recently added plugins is included in the build.